# SQL-Sum Values until reach a specific value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following 2 table:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3
Val1 T1  
Val2 T2

Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4
Val1 test  1    
Val1 test  2
Val1 T1    3
Val2 test  1
Val2 T2    2
```

I need to update the values for `Col3` of `Table 1` with the summation of Col3 of table 2 until Col2 of Table 2 reaches the value from Col2 of Table 1. So, Table 1 should look like this:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3
Val1 T1    6
Val2 T2    3
```

So, it adds up `1+2+3 = 6` for T1 and `1+2 = 3` for T2.

Basically, the Col1 for both tables will be the key. I am using `MSSQL2008` server. I tried to do this with Cursor but no luck so far.
Please note, the order by column in Table2 is a Date column (Column4). It is ordered by Desc.

Comment: what do you mean by `until Col2 of Table 2 reaches the value from Col2 of Table 1`

Comment: First, I would recommend to add a line in your example, maybe Val1/X/4 in table 2, so that readers can see that there are lines to be excluded. Second, in order to answer this, the order of the rows in table2 must be defined: what is your `order-by` in table2?

Comment: For example it should sum until Col2 of table 2 is equal to T1 which is the value for Column2 of Table 1.

Comment: @stackoverflow, is there any column for ordering the rows?

Comment: the order by in Table 2 is a date column. It is ordered in Desc order.

Comment: @stackoverflow, Did you try my answer? Is it work or not?

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using Gordon's answer since I am using SQL2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.  You can get the cutoff point using a correlated subquery:

```
update t1
    set col3 = t2.sum_col3
from t1 join
     (select t2.col1, sum(t2.col3) as sum_col3
      from t2 
      where t2.t4 >= (select tt2.t4
                      from t2 tt2 join
                           t1 tt1
                           on tt2.col1 = tt1.col1 and
                              tt2.col2 = tt1.col2
                     )
      group by t2.col1
     ) t2
     on t2.col1 = t1.col1;
```

Alternatively, you can use window functions (but not a cumulative sum):

```
update t1
    set col3 = t2.sum_col3
from t1 join
     (select t2.col1,
             sum(t2.col3) as sum_col3
      from (select t2.col1,
                   min(case when tt2.col1 = tt1.col2 then tt2.col4 end) over (partition by tt2.col1) as col4_match
            from t2 tt2 join
                 t1 tt1
                 on tt2.col1 = tt1.col1                           
           ) t2
      where col4 >= col4_match
      group by t2.col1
     ) t2
     on t2.col1 = t1.col1
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon. I ended up using your logic in my cursor since it had some additional requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this by `GROUP BY`:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(Col1 VARCHAR(10),Col2 VARCHAR(10),Col3 INT)
CREATE TABLE #Table2(Col1 VARCHAR(10),Col2 VARCHAR(10),Col3 INT,Col4 DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES('Val1','T1',0)
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES('Val2','T2',0)

INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES('Val1','test',1,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES('Val1','test',2,GETDATE()-1)
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES('Val1','T1',3,GETDATE()-2)
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES('Val1','test',4,GETDATE()-3)
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES('Val2','test',1,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES('Val2','T2',2,GETDATE()-1)

UPDATE T1
SET T1.Col3 = T2.SummationValue
FROM #Table1 T1
JOIN (
    SELECT T2.Col1,T2.Col2,SUM(T2.Col3) OVER(PARTITION BY T2.Col1 ORDER BY Col4 DESC)SummationValue
    FROM #Table2 T2
    JOIN #Table1 T1 ON T2.Col1 = T1.Col1
    )T2
ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 AND T1.Col2 = T2.Col2


SELECT * FROM #Table1

DROP TABLE #Table1
DROP TABLE #Table2
```

**OutPut:**

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
Val1    T1      6
Val2    T2      3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b603/1)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Thanks for the update. It helps me in the future.